# Displaying multiple results in a graph in Excel?

Tags: excel, graph, bar-chart, fibonacci

Hey I need to displaying the following results in a graph in excel, such that all the results are together in one graph?

```
Results     Addition    ArrayLookup Function Call   Fibonacci
Opt1        462         1259        891             14
Opt2        511         1191        865             13
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this in excel. I want the opt1, opt2 etc on the x-axis, and then the clock cycles on the y-axis, and all 4 test programs in different colours.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The chart type you're looking for is 'Clustered Bar/Column'.  As your table stands, it wants to group on columns, as just selecting your array and clicking on the chart type won't spit out the chart you want.  On Office for Mac, there is a button for 'Switch Plot' which will tell excel to group on rows.  If you can't find it, simply transposing the array and making a clustered bar/column chart should do the trick.